# How to implement in-app immediate update?

Tags: android, in-app-update

I am trying to use in app immediate update in my application and using internal test track to verify it.
I followed the documentation from here https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates 
but still not able to see the dialog for update.I have collected the log which is as follows:

AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.xxx.xxx)
AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
AppUpdateService : linkToDeath

Below is the code:

```
private fun checkForUpdate():Boolean{
        val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
        var isUpdate = false;
        Log.d("MainActivity","init isUpdate=.."+isUpdate)
// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
            ) {
                Log.d("MainActivity","Update avlbl..")
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                    // The current activity making the update request.
                    context as Activity,
                    // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                    MY_REQUEST_CODE)
                isUpdate=true
                Log.d("MainActivity","request Update avlbl.."+isUpdate)

            }
        }
        return isUpdate
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val updateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
        updateManager.appUpdateInfo
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it.updateAvailability() ==
                    UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                    updateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                        it,
                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                        context as Activity,
                        MY_REQUEST_CODE)
                    Log.d("MainActivity","oDEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS")
                }
                Log.d("MainActivity","o==DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS")
            }
    }
```